# A book about a car crashing off of an interstate or express way?

Tags: story-identification

The driver crashes his car and it goes over the barrier. Other cars are going too fast and never stop. There is a society living where he has crashed, and I think he gets robbed quickly after the crash.

This is a vague a memory of the book. The other people live under the express way or interstates and there is no way out.

Comment: Welcome to the site! You have a good start here. If you could take a look at this [guide](http://meta.scifi.stackexchange.com/a/9337/68872) to help jog your memory and [edit] in any more details, that would be great. Every little bit helps us.

Comment: What about this makes it science fiction or fantasy?

Comment: The environment of cars never stopping and it was part of a sci fi collection of stories I cannot remember. I will look elsewhere as it seems i am unwelcome here.

Comment: @user91850 - No, that was not the intent. Any detail that you can give about it helps narrow the search, so if you can edit in that you read it in a sci fi collection, when you remember reading it, etc. that can help identify it.

Comment: @JohnP - Not even I can make a user rage-quit as fast as you. I bow to the master.

Comment: Some people just have a bad day sometimes... I don’t find either amflare or JohnP‘s comment insulting or unwelcoming...

Comment: @Valorum - Really wasn't the intent. Besides, I've seen you rage people faster than that. :) I am not the master, merely a minor acolyte.

Comment: @Narusan - No. They're entirely appropriate. The user is just being overly touchy

Answer (score 8):

This sounds very similar to J.G Ballard's [Concrete Island](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/70251.Concrete_Island)

> ***On a day in April, just after three o'clock in the afternoon, Robert
>   Maitland's car crashes over the concrete parapet of a high-speed
>   highway onto the island below, where he is injured and, finally,
>   trapped.*** What begins as an almost ludicrous predicament in Concrete
>   Island soon turns into horror as Maitland - a wickedly modern Robinson
>   Crusoe - realizes that, despite evidence of other inhabitants, this
>   doomed terrain has become a mirror of his own mind.